# Framer motion animation do not played if call in the same file

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I learning framer motion in nextjs from this documentation https://www.framer.com/motion/examples/

in section Variants there is code for sidebar the original code like this
MenuToogle.tsx

```
const Path = props => (
  <motion.path
    fill="transparent"
    strokeWidth="3"
    stroke="hsl(0, 0%, 18%)"
    strokeLinecap="round"
    {...props}
  />
);

export const MenuToggle = ({ toggle }) => (
  <button onClick={toggle}>
    <svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
      <Path
        variants={{
          closed: { d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5" },
          open: { d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5" }
        }}
      />
      <Path
        d="M 2 9.423 L 20 9.423"
        variants={{
          closed: { opacity: 1 },
          open: { opacity: 0 }
        }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.1 }}
      />
      <Path
        variants={{
          closed: { d: "M 2 16.346 L 20 16.346" },
          open: { d: "M 3 2.5 L 17 16.346" }
        }}
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
);
```

example.tsx

```
export const Example = () => {
  const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useCycle(false, true);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const { height } = useDimensions(containerRef);

  return (
    <motion.nav
      initial={false}
      animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
      custom={height}
      ref={containerRef}
    >
      <motion.div className="background" variants={sidebar} />
      <Navigation />
      <MenuToggle toggle={() => toggleOpen()} />
    </motion.nav>
  );
};
```

and I tried to modificate the code to become 1 file like this (
example.tsx

```
export const Example = () => {
  const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useCycle(false, true);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const { height } = useDimensions(containerRef);

const MenuToggle = ({ toggle }) => (
  const Path = props => (
    <motion.path
      fill="transparent"
      strokeWidth="3"
      stroke="hsl(0, 0%, 18%)"
      strokeLinecap="round"
      {...props}
    />
  );
  return (<button onClick={toggle}>
    <svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
      <Path
        variants={{
          closed: { d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5" },
          open: { d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5" }
        }}
      />
      <Path
        d="M 2 9.423 L 20 9.423"
        variants={{
          closed: { opacity: 1 },
          open: { opacity: 0 }
        }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.1 }}
      />
      <Path
        variants={{
          closed: { d: "M 2 16.346 L 20 16.346" },
          open: { d: "M 3 2.5 L 17 16.346" }
        }}
      />
    </svg>
  </button>)
);

  return (
    <motion.nav
      initial={false}
      animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
      custom={height}
      ref={containerRef}
    >
      <motion.div className="background" variants={sidebar} />
      <Navigation />
      <MenuToggle toggle={() => toggleOpen()} />
    </motion.nav>
  );
};
```

But when I try put the MenuToggle code in the example.tsx, the button is work but the animation is do not play, I dont know why from moving the button inside can disable the animation, can some one explain it to me or maybe I missing something?